# Refresh an ObservableCollection when Item's property changed

Tags: windows-phone-8, refresh, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a observableCollection which is loaded with elements and displayed on the UI .At the same time the app is downloading one Icon for each element of the observable collection.I would like to display each Icon when its download finishes...

My code is working but i guess it's not the best pratice because I  bind my collection to the Ui control 2 times...I am pretty convinced that it shouldn't be necessary ...I try to implement the InotifypropertyChanged on the element's Icon property but I still have to add those lines of code to display the Icons:

```cs
 listDocsLibs = new ObservableCollection<BdeskDocLib>(listBoxGetDocsLibs);          
 llslistDocslibs.ItemsSource = listDocsLibs;
```

Below the function which dowload the Icons

```cs
List<BdeskDocLib> listBoxGetDocsLibs = new List<BdeskDocLib>();            

ObservableCollection<BdeskDocLib> listDocsLibs = new ObservableCollection<BdeskDocLib>();

 private async void LoadIconDocLibs()
        {
            foreach (var doclib in listBoxGetDocsLibs)
            {

                    byte[] Icon = await ServerFunctions.GetDocLibsIcon(doclib);

                    if (Icon != null)
                    {
                        {

                            var ms = new MemoryStream(Icon);

                            BitmapImage photo = new BitmapImage();
                            photo.DecodePixelHeight = 64;
                            photo.DecodePixelWidth = 92;
                            photo.SetSource(ms);
                            doclib.Icon = photo;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (Icon == null)
                    {
                        doclib.Icon = new BitmapImage();
                        doclib.Icon.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/BDocs/ico_ext_inconnu.png", UriKind.Relative);

                    }
                }
            }

            //IM PRETTY SURE The following code IS NOT NECESSARY BUT WHY MY UI IS NOT REFRESHING WITHOUT ?
            listDocsLibs = new ObservableCollection<BdeskDocLib>(listBoxGetDocsLibs);
            llslistDocslibs.ItemsSource = listDocsLibs;

        }
```

Comment: What is the definition of doclib.Icon? And the type of doclib, does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Doclib.Icon is a bitmap Image and yes Doclib class implement INotify property changed...public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }

Comment: And it is bound to? If you raise notification in the `Icon` property and your `Image` is bound to the property, it should automatically be updated.